# Typecast multiple responses based on the response from server in angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, rxjs-pipeable-operators

```
export class LoginResponse {
value: string;
expiration: string;
tokenType: string;
refreshToken: {
    value: string;
    expiration: string;
};
scope: [];
additionalInformation: {};
expiresIn: string;
expired: boolean;
```

}

```
export class LoginErrorResponse {
code: number;
error: string;
message: string;
sucess: boolean;
```

}

```
return this.httpClient.post(url,body,headers).pipe(map(res=><LoginResponse>res),map(res=><LoginErrorResponse>res));
```

Error: Conversion of type 'LoginResponse' to type 'LoginErrorResponse' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Property 'code' is missing in type 'LoginResponse'

I can get either of the responses from server.I want to typecast the response based on the server response and should return observable of that.

Answer (score 0):

You cast the response to `LoginResponse` and after that to a `LoginError` which are really different interfaces. So a `LoginResponse` cannot be a `LoginError` this is why you have this error.

If the login fail the API should return a **401**, and you can [catch the error](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) and casting the error response to what you want.

> Your API couldn't return 2 differents response model on the same call
>   with the same status code.